# Pasar datos de la vista al controlador en mvc php

Tags: php, mvc

Estoy empezando con php mvc nativo y no se cómo pasar los datos de la vista al controlador.

¿cuál es la manera correcta de hacerlo?

Comment: Hola Pablo. ¿Has leido la documentacion? Has probado algo ? Tienes que mostrar lo intentado para poder ayudarte. Mira [ask] para mejorarla.Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar javascript con Ajax para hacerlo

Ejemplo:

```
<script >
$(document).ready(function(){

//---Pasar Parámetros al Controlador -----

    $("#Id_del_Botón").click(function(){

    //los inputs o campos
    var parametros = {

        "nombre" : $("#nombre").val(), // #id_del_campo
        "apellido" : $("#apellido").val(),

        "operacion":"insertar_usuario"
      //Este seria el nombre de tu funcion en el modelo, en este caso, "insertar usuario"

    }

     $.ajax({
            data:  parametros,
            url:   'controlador_usuario.php', //nombre del archivo de tu controlador
            type:  'post',

        beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#modal_ingresar").modal();//LLAMOS AL MODAL QUE NOS MUESTRA EL MENSAJE, SI ES QUE TIENES ALGUNO


                    },


    });
});

//---Fin de Pasar Parametros--------------
 });

</script>
```

Controlador

```
<?php 

include_once 'modelo_usuario.php';

$objeto= new Usuario();

switch($_POST["operacion"]){

    //insertar datos de los usuarios, pasando las variables
    case "insertar_usuario":
    $objeto->nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
    $objeto->apellido=$_POST["apellido"];

    $objeto->insertar_usuario();
    break;

    //de esta forma con cada función del modelo 

    case 'buscar':

    $objeto->buscar=$_POST["buscar"]; 
    $tabla=$objeto->buscar();
    echo $tabla;
    break;



  }
 ?>
```

Modelo

Comment: Gracias master! no sabia como seguir! Saludos

Comment: Si necesitas ayuda  o tienes otras dudas me preguntas no más, me alegra que te hay sido de ayuda :D Olvide mencionar que debes de implementar JQuery, Saludos